# How to replace brackets in Lua using string.gsub?

Tags: lua, string-substitution, lua-patterns

I have a function which is used to replace some words with a few characters or numbers. I am using `string.gsub()` function in this way:

```
string.gsub(line, "[0-9%a%s/,-]+", "\t")
```

This works very good with strings with numbers, letters, spaces, `,`, and `/`. I also would like to replace brackets like `(` and `)`. But simply inserting `()` to my pattern doesn't work. I have also tried with `%(` and `%)` but it wasn't successful. How can I replace brackets in Lua using pattern in `string.gsub()` method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only characters that need to be escaped inside `[]` are `[]%-`, all of which are escaped with `%`.  As such, escaping `-` as follows works:

```
string.gsub(line, "[0-9%a%s/,%-()]+", "\t")
```

It's also probably worth mentioning that `[0-9%a]` is equivalent to `[%d%a]`, which is equivalent to `%w`.